# jQuery Mobile/ jqTouch Image width

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-website, jqtouch, jquery-mobile

I want to have a static footer image with 5 buttons for navigation in my mobile phone website.  The image is here http://www.pintum.com.au/jm/footer3a.jpg. The blue icons should be the default, the yellow icon should only be visible for the hover or active state.

*I want to know how can I make this image scale to the correct width on all mobile devices (landscape and portrait) and have links to other pages and make the current/active pages icon the yellow color?*

**What I have tried so far**

- I first tried to make a CSS Sprite but that go ugly (complex) quickly. Painful working with widths everywhere so the image scales correctly as I had no way of knowing the height in pixels since the width is dynamic. I could use JS to find the width and calculate height on the fly. But this sounds like overkill.
- Next I tried to have a single image with a width of 100% then place div overlays on top of the image. But with this solution I could not figure out how to navigate pages using JavaScript click event, or figure out how I would be able to change the image icon on the selected page http://jsbin.com/uraya5/3/ . And detrmining the correct height for the div
- Last I tried to make each button a seperate image. These seems like the easist soultion. But jQuery Mobile adds a bunch of extra styles to the button I do not know how to remove. See http://jsbin.com/uraya5/4

---

So whats the best/easiest way to do this?

- How can I remove the style around
  links?
- Or can I use a single image CSS sliding door method? To reduce HTTP request.

Comment: Here is the latest solution with hover working for each icon
http://jsbin.com/uraya5/10 . It works but means I have to make 10 images request (normal & hover) for each icon instead of just 1.

Comment: Just a thought: why do you want those icons to be soooo big?

Comment: @naugtur  the icons looks fine when the phone is portrait but are to big when the phone is landscape. I think I may stop fighting the framework and just use it how it was meant to be used by following the example here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html under 3rd party icon sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out

See soultion here http://jsbin.com/uraya5/10/
I had to:

1. Set width to 19% of each button for
   some reason there is spacing between
   each button so 20% does not work.
2. Set ui-bar-a  background to black so
   it hides the spaces between my
   images
3. Use this JS code to navigate pages  $.mobile.changePage($("#about"),
   "flip", true, true);

I would still like to use a single image instead of having 5 different images to reduce http calls. So if anyone finds a eligant soultion for this please let me know.

Comment: @naugtur when I wrap an "a href" tag around the image jQuery Mobile adds in a ton of unwanted tags and styles that destroy my layout. See what happens with the 1st icon as a link http://jsbin.com/uraya5/11

Comment: o. that's bad... a CSS override could be possible, but I'm not sure.